# server 2012 RDS cannot connect to virtual desktop in lab

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rds, remote-desktop-services

I am trying an evaluation of remote desktops on Azure. I’d like to be able to demo the product and I’ve created a couple virtual machines, installed RDS and created a collection, but even though after logging into the web rd site, I see my remote desktop listed but everything I’ve tried I cannot connect and log into the desktop session. I’ve tried many fixes but just getting frustrated. I’m sure I’m missing something simple and I’ve gone through several tutorials and tech-net articles but I cannot connect to the hosted remote desktop session. I added a dns host record on my local client to use the IP instead of the DNS name for my trial servers, but I still get the error below:
[image]
 [image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you ticked "Allow remote assistance connections to this computer" in "remote settings" on your target hosts ? (maybe a silly question...)

Comment: Yes I even unchecked "only with Network Level Authentication but still no luck. I was, however, able to connect to the RDS object from an different internal vm on the same network. So this leads me to believe that DNS or security is broken between my external network and Azure.

Comment: Are you able to connect with basic RDP (means using mstsc) to 137.135.9.160 by using both IP and hostname from your Azure server ?

Comment: External to the Azure network, no I cannot mstsc to the IP or hostname. Internal to the Azure network, I cannot mstsc to the IP 137... but I can mstsc to jclabrd01.nethealth and I can do the internal IP fine.

Comment: Ok i think you have FW (or something similar : ACL...) issues from External network, that is another problem. So first we are going to concentrate on the internal network issue. So you are able to do basic RDP using target IP and target hostname from the internal network, from your Azure server ?

Comment: Yes I can connect with basic RDP using target IP and hostname from internal network/azure server.